# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tan(2n+1)}{(2+n)^{1/2}}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following series converge absolutely?$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tan(2n+1)}{(2+n)^{1/2}}$$

So basically I have a few question similar to this one  and I'm not sure if I am proving the (absolute) convergence properly. How do I solve it and similar exercises?
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: sqrt(2+n), idk why it only got the bracket over there

Comment: You have to use curly braces around any exponent that includes more than one character.

Comment: whoops, thanks @AdrianKeister

Comment: @AndrewLi The exercise is as stated "check absolute/conditional convergence of the following series-and it's listed afterwards"; would the ratio test be enough/how do i handle the absolute part? the tangent part bugs me to be exact

Comment: uh, huh, I get it. But now I have a new problem-I get a limit of tan(2x+3)*sqrt(k+1) over tan(2x+1)*sqrt(k+2). And I don't know how to solve it lol. Online limit solver websites aren't of much help. (one does x=n*pi, but i don't see how that helps) Any ideas/resources i can check out?

Comment: I expect the ratio test fails.  liminf < 1 and limsup > 1 ... graphically, it looks like the root test has a chance for limsup < 1 .  Although maybe limsup = 1 ??

Comment: I'll ask the professor tomorrow, it seems I'm missing a bigger piece of knowledge than I thought I am. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

I will show that
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{|\tan(2n+1)|}{(2+n)^{1/2}}
$
diverges.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2+n)^{1/2}}
$
diverges
so it is enough
to show that
$\tan(2n+1)$
is very often not small.

Suppose
$|\tan(2n+1)|$
is small,
say less than $.1$.
Then
$\tan(2n+3)
=\dfrac{\tan(2n+1)+\tan(2)}{1-\tan(2n+1)\tan(2)}
\approx\dfrac{\tan(2n+1)-2.185}{1+\tan(2n+1)2.185}
$
so
$|\tan(2n+3)|
\gt \dfrac{1}{1+.2185}
\gt 0.82
$.

Therefore
$\dfrac{|\tan(2n+1)|}{(2+n)^{1/2}}+\dfrac{|\tan(2n+3)|}{(2+n+1)^{1/2}}
\gt \dfrac{0.82}{(3+n)^{1/2}}
$

and the sum of these diverges.

In other words,
either
$\dfrac{|\tan(2n+1)|}{(2+n)^{1/2}}
\ge \dfrac{0.1}{(2+n)^{1/2}}
$
or
$\dfrac{|\tan(2n+1)|}{(2+n)^{1/2}}+\dfrac{|\tan(2n+3)|}{(2+n+1)^{1/2}}
\gt \dfrac{0.82}{(3+n)^{1/2}}
$
and the sum of
either of these
diverges.

Comment: OK, to give an update, my professor said that the pi/4 needed to be counted as if inside the tan(-.-), which makes the series alternating. Thanks for you time and answer though, much appreciated. :)

Comment: What $\pi/4$? Don't see one.

Comment: oh yeah, i didnt write the full series when asking the question. there is a pi/4 there> (2n+1)pi/4 but the way its written is like a constant so i ommited it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any $\alpha\in (\frac 32, \frac \pi 2)$ and note that for $k\geq 0$, the interval $(\frac \pi 2 +k\pi -\alpha, \frac \pi 2 +k\pi +\alpha)$ has length $2\alpha\in(3, \pi)$, and thus contains at least one odd integer (and at most two).

Note also that for $x\in (\frac \pi 2 +k\pi -\alpha, \frac \pi 2 +k\pi +\alpha)$, $|\tan(x)|>|\tan(\frac \pi 2 -\alpha)|$.

Each $2n+1$ falls into some $(\frac \pi 2 +k\pi -\alpha, \frac \pi 2 +k\pi +\alpha)$, and in that case $2n+1\leq (k+1)\pi$, hence $n\leq \frac{(k+1)\pi -1}{2}$.

Thus $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\tan(2n+1)}{(2+n)^{1/2}}\right|\geq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{|\tan(\frac \pi 2 -\alpha)|}{\left(2+\frac{(k+1)\pi -1}{2}\right)^{1/2}}$$

The last series obviously diverges (it's of the order $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$).

Comment: OK, to give an update, my professor said that the pi/4 needed to be counted as if inside the tan(-.-), which makes the series alternating. Thanks for you time and answer though, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Still, the incorrect statement yields an interesting problem... The method I employed can be reused to deal with the convergence of similar series.